# AngularJS Controller function - TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: angularjs, jakarta-ee, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, gmail-api

I am creating an email application that makes RESTful calls to Google APIs. I am using AngularJS and Java. I have had some success so far but I am unable to delete an email because I keep getting this error: TypeError: object is not a function.

My Angular knowledge is limited.

In my html I call the function deleteEmail and pass an email id.

Here is the controller:

```
app.controller('InboxController', function($rootScope, $scope, $cookies,
    $location, InboxService) {

$rootScope.loggedIn = true;

$scope.emails = InboxService.getMessages().success(function(jsonData) {

    $scope.emails = jsonData;
});

$scope.deleteEmail = function(id) {

    $scope.id = {

        'id' : id
    };

    // Parse to JSON
    var responseJSON = angular.toJson($scope.id);

    // Make call to InboxService
    var response = InboxService().del(responseJSON).success(
            function(jsonData) {

                response = jsonData;

                if (response == 'success') {

                    alert('Message deleted');
                } else {

                    alert('Message not deleted');
                }
            });
}
```

});

The method $scope.emails works fine. It is the $scope.deleteEmail that is giving the error.

Here is the service:

```
app.factory('InboxService', function InboxService($http) {

var exports = {};

// Get a list of all emails
exports.getMessages = function() {

    return $http.get('resources/inbox/get').error(function(data) {
        console.log('There was an error!', data);
    });
};

// Delete an email
exports.del = function(id) {

    console.log('id ' + id);

    return $http({

        method : 'POST',
        url : 'resources/inbox/delete',
        data : id,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    });
};

return exports;
```

});

I don't think I am getting as far as the service though. The problem seems to be with the controller.

Console output:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
at Scope.$scope.deleteEmail (http://localhost:8080/NewProject/js/controllers.js:64:18)
at Parser.functionCall (http://localhost:8080/NewProject/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10903:21)
at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (http://localhost:8080/NewProject/bower_components/angular/angular.js:19259:17)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8080/NewProject/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12811:28)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8080/NewProject/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12909:23)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/NewProject/bower_components/angular/angular.js:19264:23)
at http://localhost:8080/NewProject/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2853:10
```

Comment: show the console output. what is the error you're getting?

Comment: updated with console output

Comment: perhaps you meant to use `$http.post( ...`

Comment: I used the same http post format to send an email and it works.

Comment: Please indent and format your code properly so it's easy to read and spot mistakes. And Java has nothing to do with Javascript.

Comment: Thats how Eclipse formatted it. I have not shown the Java part as I do not believe that is the problem. The Service makes a call to the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Pls be sure you called deleteEmail(id) from within html with right syntax without $scope

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteEmail(email.id)">Delete</button> The correct id is being passed to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I changed the Controller delete method to this:

```
$scope.delete = function (id) {
    InboxService.delete(id).success(function() {

        $scope.loadInbox();
    });
};
```

And the Service method to this:

```
// Delete an email
exports.delete = function(id) {

    console.log('id ' + id);

    return $http({

        method : 'DELETE',
        url : 'resources/inbox/delete',
        data: id,
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    });
}
```